# TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined

Tags: node.js, electron

I installed `electron-json-storage` (version 4.1.5) to my application and it suddenly stopped to work with following message:

```
C:\electron4\electron_app>node src/main.js
C:\electron4\electron_app\node_modules\electron-json-storage\lib\utils.js:30
const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app;
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\electron4\electron_app\node_modules\electron-json-storage\lib\utils.js:30:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\electron4\electron_app\node_modules\electron-json-storage\lib\storage.js:37:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

I tried to clean node_modules and re-isntall it, but no luck. I suppose it's not directly related to electron-json-storage, because when I install any new package I am facing this. Sometimes cleaning node_modules and re-installing them helps, but this is not the solution.

Is there any general thing I am missing?

Comment: Um that looks like a bug in their code?? The `remote` module only exists in the main process, so `remote.app` would always break when run in that context. Not sure how that's supposed to work... Try creating an issue on their github page...

Comment: This is presumably only a problem when you `require` that npm package, right? If you comment out the require it works?

Comment: Look [here](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/573)